# Pandas write blank values to CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'data': [4, np.nan]})
df
   data
0   4.0
1   NaN
```

This DataFrame is generated after parsing data from various sources and sometimes I do not have values for some integer fields.

Eventually this data is to be stored in a CSV and I'd like to store this as an integer 4 and a blank. I have tried using `replace({numpy.nan: None})` and also `replace({numpy.nan: ''})` but that didn't help.

How do I ensure I get an integer 4 and a blank when this gets exported to CSV? The end goal is to use this CSV to load it into Redshift/Postgres which has explicitly defined datatypes.

**Update:**
How am I writing this file?

```
with s3fs.open(s3_path, 'wb') as f:
        s = StringIO()
        df.to_csv(s, index=False, header=True)
        f.write(s.getvalue().encode('utf-8'))
        s = None
```

Comment: i did not get any problem in saving the file. I did `df.to_csv('mydf.csv', index=False)`

Comment: how are you writing the file ?

Comment: @YOLO Updated the question. I am writing this as a file to S3.

Comment: okay, may be you should update the question title, that changes everything. are you using boto3 ?

Comment: @YOLO When I do `to_csv`, I get 4.0 and a blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify the `dtype` as `int`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'data': [4, np.nan]}, dtype=int)
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

**output.csv**

```
data
4
""
```

**EDIT**

If you need to specify the data types on a dataframe you already created you can use [`.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html#pandas-dataframe-astype) on the dataframe.
If your dataframe contains NaN values, you should convert to `object` type:

```
df['data'] = df['data'].astype(object)
```

Comment: This seems like a good direction to go. I elided the fact that the DataFrame is constructed using `DataFrame.from_records` and a list of dictionaries. How do I specify a dtype on a dataframe constructed that way?

Comment: I edited my question. AFAIK, you can't specify datatypes when you pass a list of dictionaries to `DataFrame.from_records` but you can change the dtypes later on the dataframe.

Comment: I tried `astype(int)` but NaNs cannot be converted to int

Comment: You can then use `astype(object)`. It's not the healthiest thing to do, but it's the only way to have ints and NaNs in the same column.

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
df.to_csv(s, index=False, header=True)
```

should just give you the 4 and empty row in CSV as you expected. But if you mean to replace the NaN into blank, this is how I can do it:

```
>>> df.mask(df.isna(), None)
   data
0     4
1  None
```

Feel free to replace `None` above with whatever you like, such as, `""`.

Comment: This does not help when saving to CSV.

Comment: yes, saving to CSV will be the same either way. I can't remember which version of pandas will not write blank for NaN values. After all, the default placeholder for missing values in pandas is NaN

Comment: Well my issue is that I do not want my integer to become a float when I write this dataframe out :)

Answer (score 0):

Uncomplicated!

```
df.data = df.data.fillna(' ')
df.to_csv('anyfilename.csv', sep=',')
```

Basically what fillna does is fills all the NaN values of the 'data' column of the dataframe by any desired value (in our case "  " blank). Then we are using the to_csv method to write the entire dataframe to the desired csv file.